# Dynamic multi level Menu and submenu php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a menu that needs to be created dynamically from the database. need to have menu and submenu

```
 <?php

$sql =('SELECT rubriques.id,rubriques.intitule,actions.intitulee,actions.lien,actions.idr   FROM rubriques,actions where rubriques.id=actions.idr ');
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
    {

while($row=$stmt->fetch_assoc())
{
    extract($row);
    ?>

          <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><?php echo $intitule; ?></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">

                <li><a href="<?php echo $lien; ?>"><?php echo $intitulee; ?></a></li>
              </ul>



    <?php

   }  }         

  ?>
```

for example (wht i want):

if A is menu item and A1  A2 A3 are sub menu item what i want is a menu like this
A

A1

A2

A3

but what i get  whith this code is

A     A     A

A1  A2  A3

````
 ```CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `intitulee` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `lien` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `idr` int(255) NOT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;



     INSERT INTO `actions` (`id`, `intitulee`, `lien`, `idr`) VALUES
     (1, 'Estivage', 'estirage.php', 1),
     (4, 'Excursions', 'exurcions.html', 1),
     (5, 'Equipe foot', '404.html', 2),
     (6, 'Clubs de sports ', '404.html', 0),
      (7, 'Fete des femmes', '404.html', 3),


 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rubriques` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`intitule` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;



   INSERT INTO `rubriques` (`id`, `intitule`) VALUES
   (1, 'Voyages'),
   (2, 'ACTIVITES CULTURELLES ET SPORTIVES.'),
   (3, 'FETES & RECEPTIONS'),
````

Comment: put `<li class="active"><a href="index.html"><?php echo $intitule; ?></a>` put this line out of `while loop` . That line is iterating everything thats why you get above output .

Comment: he will not import intitule

Comment: undifinied variable intitule

Comment: is your `menu` and `sub-menu` is in same table ? can you show your table structure with some data in it.?

Comment: no in different table menu in rubriques and sub-menu in actions

Comment: i will add the database in the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `menu` and `sub-menu` are in different table you can select `menu` first and then select `sub-menu` depending on the menu selected .i.e :

```
 <?php
//getting menu first
$sql  = 'SELECT id,intitule FROM rubriques';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
       //getting values  
        $intitule = $row['intitule '];
        $idr = $row['id']; ?>
       <!--your menu-->
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><?php
        echo $intitule;
     ?></a>
  <?php
   //passing the id from first to action table for compare and retrieve that rows only
        $sql1  = 'SELECT  * FROM actions where idr= ' . $idr;
        $stmt1 = $conn->query($sql1);
   ?>
     <ul class="dropdown">
    <?php
        while ($row1 = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
            $lien  = $row1['lien'];
            $intitulee = $row1['intitulee'];
    ?>

        <!--your submenu-->
  <li><a href="<?php echo $lien;?>"><?php echo $intitulee; ?></a></li>

     <?php

        }
    ?>
       </ul> <!--closing ul -->

     </li>
<?php
  }//closing while
} //closing if
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much but its generate a problem Undefined index: lien Undefined index: intitulee

Comment: What output did you got? Did you updated your code ? Also , i have made one mistake in second `while loop` Change to ->`while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch_assoc())` i.e instead of `$stmt1` i  have written there `$stmt`

Comment: yes i have edited thank you very much but the code show me one menu item with

Comment: one menu item with many sub menu and that's good but i have 3 in database

Comment: Why only one menu is printing , as per above code , all `menu` item and `sub menu` should be printed, did you add while loop as in above for 1st query ?

Comment: thanks for your help i have added while in the first statment

Comment: Does that print all menu that are present in your table ?

Comment: ok  after two days i will "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Answer (score 0):

It would be more usual to see that query written like this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT r.id
     , r.intitule
     , a.intitulee
     , a.lien
     , a.idr   
  FROM rubriques r
  JOIN actions a
    ON a.idr = r.id
 ORDER 
    BY r.id;
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

the final code

```
  <?php
   //getting menu first
   $sql  = 'SELECT id,intitule FROM rubriques ';
   $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
   if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
   //getting values  
    $intitule =$row['intitule'];
    $id = $row['id']; ?>
   <!--your menu-->
<li class="active"><a href="index.html"><?php
    echo $intitule;
 ?></a>

 <?php
   //passing the id from first to action table for compare and retrieve that rows only
       $sql1  = 'SELECT  * FROM actions where idr= ' . $id;
    $stmt1 = $conn->query($sql1);
       ?>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <?php
        while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lien = $row1['lien'];
        $intitulee = $row1['intitulee'];
?>

    <!--your submenu-->
<li><a href="<?php echo $lien;?>"><?php echo $intitulee; ?></a></li>

 <?php

    } 
?>
   </ul> <!--closing ul -->
 </li>
   <?php
    }}
      $conn->close();
     //closing if
     ?>
```